# Python Parsing with lxml

Tags: python, html, parsing, csv, lxml

I've created the following **scraper** for NFL play-by-play data. It writes the results to a csv file and does everything I need it to except I don't know how to attach a column for who actually has possession of the ball in each line of the csv file.
I can grab the text from the "home" and "away" `<tr>` tag to show who is playing in the game for query purposes later, but I need the **scraper** to recognize when possession changes (goes from home to away or vice versa). I'm fairly new to Python and have tried different indention but I don't think that's the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I feel like the answer is beyond my scope of understanding.

I also realize that my code probably isn't the most Pythonic but I'm still learning. I'm using Python 2.7.9.

```
import lxml
from lxml import html
import csv
import urllib2
import re

game_date = raw_input('Enter game date: ')

data_html = 'http://www.cbssports.com/nfl/gametracker/playbyplay/NFL_20160109_PIT@CIN'

url = urllib2.urlopen(data_html).read()

data = lxml.html.fromstring(url)


plays = data.cssselect('tr#play')
home = data.cssselect('tr#home')
away = data.cssselect('tr#away')

csvfile = open('C:\\DATA\\PBP.csv', 'a')
writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

for play in plays:

    frame = []
    play = play.text_content()

    down = re.search(r'\d', play)
    if down == None:
        pass
    else:
        down = down.group()

    dist = re.search(r'-(\d+)', play)
    if dist == None:
        pass
    else:
        dist = dist.group(1)

    field_end = re.search(r'[A-Z]+', play)

    if field_end == None:
        pass
    else:
        field_end = field_end.group()

    yard_line = re.search(r'[A-Z]+([\d]+)', play)

    if yard_line == None:
        pass
    else:
        yard_line = yard_line.group(1)

    desc = re.search(r'\s(.*)', play)
    if desc == None:
        pass
    else:
        desc = desc.group()

    time = re.search(r'\((..*\d)\)\s', play)
    if time == None:
        pass
    else:
        time = time.group(1)

    for team in away:
        teamA = team.text_content()
        teamA = re.search(r'(\w+)\s', teamA)
        teamA = teamA.group(1)
        teamA = teamA.upper()

    for team in home:
        teamH = team.text_content()
        teamH = re.search(r'(\w+)\s', teamH)
        teamH = teamH.group(1)
        teamH = teamH.upper()

    frame.append(game_date)
    frame.append(down)
    frame.append(dist)
    frame.append(field_end)
    frame.append(yard_line)
    frame.append(time)
    frame.append(teamA)
    frame.append(teamH)
    frame.append(desc)

    writer.writerow(frame)

csvfile.close()
```

Comment: I did a poor job explaining what I want so I definitely apologize. As the for loop iterates through the list, I want it to return the home teams name when it encounters the 'home' tag. Then continue returning the home team name until encountering the 'away' tag. Then do the same thing for the away team. Hope that makes it a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to append another value to the frame, for each row, which an indication of whether the possession changed.

After:

```
frame.append(desc)
```

add:

```
if teamA == teamH:
    frame.append("Same possession")
else:
    frame.append("Changed possession")
```

(note this assumes the team names are consistent, no extra spaces/padding/formatting in the teamA/teamH values).

You don't have to use strings, for example you could put 0 for no change and 1 for a change of possession.

HTH
Barny